# setup a SMPP Server in Java

Tags: java, smpp, opensmpp

Using Kannel I have setup a gateway to communicate to SMSC and send messages.

Now I want to setup a simple SMPP server in Java to receive messages using SMPP protocol.
I tried finding online, am new to this field and do not have clear idea about it.

- Can this be done via the existing SMSBox & BearerBox?
- Do I need to have a separate server altogether?
- I was thinking of using "[OpenSMPP](http://opensmpp.org/)" to setup the server. Is that correct?

Also could you please let me know if there are any guides, docs explaining how to do the same?

Also is **OpenSMPP** is an option?

Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Check if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430537/how-to-write-simple-smpp-server

Comment: Hi Akhil, Thanks fo reply. I saw that link., I wanted to know if I can try to do something in Java.